# Different results when casting FLT_MAX to unsigned char across C/C++ compilers

Tags: c++, c

I was toying around with some cast operations at [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), specifically this trivial program using Language = C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%u",(unsigned char) FLT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs 255.

That output is consistent across the OnlineGDB Language options C++, C++ 14 and C++ 17 (I assume the code is GCC compiled).

**However** when running the same program at OnlineGDB Language with options TurboC, TurboC/C++, and on a Windows 10 system with Visual Studio 2015 the program result is 0, not 255.

Having a cursory look over compiler flags I saw nothing regarding this behavior (of course I may have missed one).

What is causing the differing cast results?

Comment: First of all, C and C++ are two *very* different languages. There's just no such things as a "C/C++" language. Secondly,  Turbo C++ is *ancient* and was discontinued long before C++ was actually standardized. It shouldn't be used for anything any more, except as a curiosity.

Comment: I _believe_ that if the floating point value is not representable in the destination integer type, the result is undefined, in which case, you’re lucky not to get nasal demons. Someone well-versed in the standards could probably provide a reference.

Comment: For example, microsoft defines it as undefined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/conversions-from-floating-point-types?view=msvc-160 : `A floating-point value that is converted to an integral type is first truncated by discarding any fractional value. If this truncated value is representable in the result type, the result must be that value. When it isn't representable, the result value is undefined.`

Comment: FLT_MAX (and similar constants) have implementation-defined values. All the C standard requires is that FLT_MAX have a minimum value of 1E37.

Comment: There are multiple conversions happening in your code, one which leads to *another* (and different) undefined behavior... The first conversion is the explicit cast to `unsigned char`. The second is the implicit integer promotion to an **`int`**. And since `%u` is for `unsigned int` and you provide an `int` argument you have mismatching format specifier and argument type, which is UB.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Max and Some programmer dude, thanks!